# Can not execute SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I have the following procedure into which I pass a string parameter, for example `,2,3,`. The procedure should return a set of rows where `CategoryId` is equal to `2` or `3`:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetItemListProcedure]
    (@CategoriesIdString VARCHAR(1000))
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @SQLQuery NVARCHAR(MAX);

    SET @SQLQuery = N'SELECT Item.Id, Item.ModelId, Item.ItemCode, Item.CategoryId, 
            (SELECT TOP (1) Category.CategoryName FROM Category WHERE Category.Id = Item.CategoryId) AS CategoryName
                      FROM Item 
                      LEFT OUTER JOIN Category ON Item.CategoryId = Category.Id'; 

    IF (@CategoriesIdString IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN
        SET @SQLQuery += N' WHERE CHARINDEX('','' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), Item.CategoryId) + '','', '' +  @CategoriesIdString + '') > 0';
    END

    DECLARE @ParmDefinition NVARCHAR(600);
    SET @ParmDefinition = N'@categoriesId VARCHAR(1000);

    PRINT @SQLQuery;

    EXEC sp_executesql @SQLQuery, @ParmDefinition, @categoriesId = @CategoriesIdString

    RETURN 0
```

This procedure, for some reason, returns no records.

However, if I run the following query:

```
DECLARE @CategoriesIdString VARCHAR(1000)
SET @CategoriesIdString = ',2,3,';

SELECT 
   Item.Id, Item.ModelId, Item.ItemCode, Item.CategoryId, 
    (SELECT TOP (1) Category.CategoryName 
     FROM Category 
     WHERE Category.Id = Item.CategoryId) AS CategoryName
FROM 
   Item 
LEFT OUTER JOIN             
   Category ON Item.CategoryId = Category.Id
WHERE 
   CHARINDEX(',' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), Item.CategoryId) + ',', @CategoriesIdString) > 0
```

then I got some rows.

What do I do wrong in my stored procedure?

I also tried like this:

```
SET @SQLQuery += N' WHERE CHARINDEX('','' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), Item.CategoryId) + '','', @CategoriesIdString) > 0';
```

But get an error:

> {"Must declare the scalar variable \"@CategoriesIdString\"."}

Comment: do a "print @sqlquery" to see what the query looks like just before executing. Then you can just copy and paste that into management studio and execute directly to see where the syntax is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to use dynamic `T-SQL` statement in this case. One of the ways is to use something like this:

```
DECLARE @TempXML XML = CONVERT(XML, '<t>' + REPLACE(@CategoriesIdString, ',', '</t><t>') + '</t>')

;WITH DataSource ([CategoryId]) AS
(
    SELECT T.c.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)')
    FROM @TempXML.nodes('/t') AS T(c)
    WHERE LEN(T.c.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)')) > 0
)
SELECT Item.Id
      ,Item.ModelId
      ,Item.ItemCode
      ,Item.CategoryId
      ,(SELECT TOP (1) Category.CategoryName FROM Category WHERE Category.Id = Item.CategoryId) AS CategoryName
FROM Item 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Category 
    ON Item.CategoryId = Category.Id
LEFT JOIN DataSource
    ON Item.CategoryId = DataSource.CategoryId
WHERE DataSource.CategoryId IS NOT NULL 
    OR @CategoriesIdString IS NULL
```

The idea is to filter by `@CategoriesIdString` parameter if it is `NOT NULL` using `LEFT JOIN`.