# Dynamic generating columns in SQL Server procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I need help with my stored procedure.

I have tables: `Items` (`Id, ItemName`), `Suppliers`, `Quotes`.

`Quotes` table has following structure: `Id, ItemId, SupplierId, Quote`

1) Suppose I have N suppliers. How can I generate the table with the following columns:

```
ItemName   Supplier1Quote   Supplier2Quote  ...  Supplier-n-Quote
```

To be exact, suppose I have 3 suppliers and the following `Quote` table:

```
Id  ItemId  SupplierId  Quote
------------------------------
1   1       1           4.00
2   1       2           5.00
3   2       3           7.00
```

I want to get:

```
ItemName   Supplier1   Supplier2  Supplier3
--------------------------------------------
ItemName1  4.00        5.00
ItemName2                         7.00
```

2) How to do the same with dynamic number of suppliers which Id will be passed into this procedure?

By now, I pass a string parameter which contains `suppliersId` divided and wrapped by `,` and get these Id that way (thanks to gotqn [Can not execute SQL Server stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28570371/can-not-execute-sql-server-stored-procedure)):

```
DECLARE @SuppliersIdString VARCHAR(1000)
--SET @SuppliersIdString = ',2,'; --

DECLARE @TempXML XML = CONVERT(XML, '<t>' + REPLACE(@SuppliersIdString, ',', '</t><t>') + '</t>');
WITH DataSource ([SuppliersId]) AS
(
    SELECT T.c.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)')
    FROM @TempXML.nodes('/t') AS T(c)
    WHERE LEN(T.c.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)')) > 0
)
```

That way I get `SuppliersId` but don't know what to do next (see question1)

Answer (score -1):

Use SQL Server pivot . [MSDN Pivot and Unpivot](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx)

```
select * from Supplier s pivot ( sum (Quote) FOR SupplierId   IN ( [1],[2],[3],[4],[5] )) as p
```